# post image to twitter using update_with_media rest API

Tags: twitter, oauth, mgtwitterengine

I am using update_with_media Rest API to post a picture to twitter. I am getting HHTP 410 error everytime when I hit the API

My code snippet is : In SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.m

```
- (NSString *) _uploadImage:(UIImage *)image requestType:(MGTwitterRequestType)requestType responseType:(MGTwitterResponseType)responseType
{

    NSString *boundary = @"----------------------------991990ee82f7";

    NSURL *finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json"];
    if (!finalURL) {
        return nil;
    }


    OAMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [[[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:finalURL
                                                                       consumer:self.consumer
                                                                          token:_accessToken
                                                                          realm: nil
                                                              signatureProvider:nil] autorelease];

    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];

    // Set headers for client information, for tracking purposes at Twitter.
    [theRequest setValue:_clientName    forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Twitter-Client"];
    [theRequest setValue:_clientVersion forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Twitter-Client-Version"];
    [theRequest setValue:_clientURL     forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Twitter-Client-URL"];


    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [theRequest setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:0];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"media[]\"; filename=\"1.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) base64EncodingWithLineLength:0]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"status\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Honeymoon uploads image\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // modificaiton from the base clase
    // our version "prepares" the oauth url request
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [theRequest prepare];

    [theRequest setHTTPBody:body];

    // Create a connection using this request, with the default timeout and caching policy,
    // and appropriate Twitter request and response types for parsing and error reporting.
    MGTwitterHTTPURLConnection *connection;
    connection = [[MGTwitterHTTPURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest
                                                            delegate:self
                                                         requestType:requestType
                                                        responseType:responseType];

    if (!connection) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        [_connections setObject:connection forKey:[connection identifier]];
        [connection release];
    }

    return [connection identifier];  
}
```

In my MGTwitterEngine.m

```
- (NSString *)upploadd:(UIImage *)img status:(NSString *)status
{
    return [self _uploadImage:img requestType:MGTwitterImageRequest responseType:(MGTwitterStatus)];
}
```

Please help me to find out the error. I am really confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With API v1.1, use api.twitter.com as the domain instead of upload.twitter.com.Try using this url

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json

Comment: thanks for the help, the image is getting posted but the status is not getting posted...any help here

Comment: Change the requestType

Answer (score 0):

for the status share just replace the below code

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"status\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",status] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

with the following code

```
 //Status
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"status\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[statusStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```